# How to show alert message with define range in php from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

In mysql there are 1 to 10 numbers available in table colum, i am fetching number and want to show alert message when number range 1 to 10 or more there are show alert "numbers are enaught". You can alert message show through javascript but embedded with php.

```
<?php
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM dndorder ORDER BY display_order";
    $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
    $data_records = array();
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)) {
        echo $row['id'];
        if($row==10){
            foreach (range($row, 10) as $number) {
                echo 'exceed num';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't use `LIMIT 10` in query?

Comment: because numbers can increase in data colum may be number can more than 10 or 30 etc. I am concerned about PHP rather than MYSQL. If i use Limit 10 in query so can you guide me how can i show alert message in php?

Comment: So you want select all rows then if the rows is > 10 alert it to user?

Answer (score 0):

@Simone Rossaini

[this range define 0 to 9 values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJJ20.jpg)

[this range define 0 to 9 but disorder way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0612s.jpg)

Actually the numbers keep changing and the numbers keep increasing.

For example if row still showing 10 but now i want to increase some more row with others colums data may be row get reach 2 more so number will show till 0 to 11 total count 12. I want show message, when last value increase with assending order like 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 last value increase 12 just show message "Last value has been increased is 12".